# App Crashes on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-cursor, onactivityresult

Im new on android, and in this app, you need to fill some edittext, like name, email, etc, then add a picture using a button that opens gallery or  another button that takes a picture and and after this you have to push a button to send this info to a db. It works if i add the picture from the gallery, and send this info, but when i do the same taking a picture the app crashes. Im not sure what could be the problem and i'd really appreciate someone help me out. Or tell me what can be causing this problem.

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){

try {
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), (filePath));
getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, filePath));
} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 }else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            areaLeyendaImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            areaFotoCargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textoimagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            area_cerrarIagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cerrarImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonChoose.setError(null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
08-20 23:23:53.320 11022-11022/com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta, PID: 11022
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC.getPath(TerminosYC.java:579)
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC$1.onClick(TerminosYC.java:355)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: `cursor.moveToFirst();` this code is throwing error means cursor is null.

Comment: But i dont know why is this. or how to solve it, since it doesnt happen the same when attaching a picture from gallery. @ArjunGurung

Comment: Use different Cursor variable in this line:                                           'cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);'

Comment: You mean like saying if requestcode== CAM_REQUEST then  'cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query( android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_UR‌​I, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);  or what do you mena buddy? @Danger

Comment: Closing cursor could be the problem. Try using different Cursor variables. Define two cursor variables.                                                                public String getPath(Uri uri) {
   
    Cursor cursor2 = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor2.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor2.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor2.close();
    return path;
}

Comment: Thanks, i will do it, and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Seems no efforts!
anyway try this

```
if(mCursor!=null && mCursor.getCount()>0 ){
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

The reason is your #uri ,as you are getting null value there.
First make sure that you are getting proper image uri or not!

Comment: Thanks, lemme try it.

Comment: Adding that code, the app crashes in another line String document_id = cursor.getString(0);

Comment: could you try to debug it ? is compiler goes in to if condition as i mention in above answer. If NO then you are .query to your corsor  in wrong manner.

Comment: while debbugin it i am not able to see any errors, probably im not debbuging properly.

Comment: you need to learn and debugging your code first :) .No worry ,for the ease you can put Log or System.out.print inside if statement in the last ,and you can trace that statement will execute or not.

Comment: It seems that it's not executed, since i don' get to see my message and then the app crashes :/